# Multiple Textbox if Condition ( if a certain value is Greater than certain value do this )

Tags: c#, winforms

I am writing a code in C# winforms using Visual studio 2013

I have 20 plus textboxes and panel..each textbox is inside a panel.
I want to put a condition that when the value of the textbox reach a certain number the backcolor of panel would change..

Please see sample code

```
        nes1_hr.Text = n1.TotalHours.ToString("N1");

          if ((n1.TotalHours >= 800)&& (n1.TotalHours <= 980))

        {
            panel1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Orange;
        }
        else if (n1.TotalHours >= 980)
        {
            panel1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        }
        else
        {
            panel1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.YellowGreen;
            panel1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
        }
```

this code works for 1 panel...can you help me shorten the code for all panel that i have?

this is what my Form looks like
[image]

Comment: You should consider building a UserControl that contains all the logic, so when *something* changes the value of its TextBox, the UC *reacts* to the change. No other code needed and all the logic in one single *place*.

Comment: @Mikael im looking to it now..thanks,

Comment: @ Jimi can you set me an example?thanks in advance